# Symmetry properties of time and space in non-inertial frames

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, symmetry, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

Are symmetry properties of time and space true for non-inertial frames? If yes, how? If no, why not?

Please, can you explain?

We already know that an important feature of inertial frames is the fact that time and space possess definite symmetry properties with respect to them.

Comment: Look up general covariance.

Comment: Can you clarify which properties you are referring to?

Comment: The uniformity of time, the uniformity and isotropy of space.

Answer (score 1):

A good example of a non-inertial frame is the one with gravitation, such as on Earth. The uniformity of time translates into energy conservation. If you do something in a constant gravity (or, according to the equivalence principle, in a constant acceleration), such as without lifting things up or dropping them down, then the energy is obviously conserved. This simply means that, if you do the same thing tomorrow instead of today, the result would be exactly the same. So time is still uniform, but only locally, meaning, if you don't lift things up or drop them down.

The picture is a bit different, if you start lifting things up. This takes energy, so energy is not conserved. However, this process is fully reversible. The energy is released back when these things are dropped down. Therefore it is easy to introduce a value called "potential energy" as a component of the full energy and thus restore the energy balance.

Another way of looking at this is to consider the fact that time moves slower closer to Earth and faster away from it. So when you lift an object, you actually move it from a region of a slower moving time to a region of a faster moving time. This way time is not uniform and therefore energy is not conserved. Well, yes indeed, you need to invest some energy in lifting an object.

The proper understanding of the energy conservation law is not that energy never changes, but that time and energy are in a symmetry relationship. This way, if time in not uniform, you simply introduce a correction component to the full energy called "potential energy". Then your full energy is still conserved in a non uniform time.

So the answer to your question is that in the direction of acceleration time is not uniform, but the time/energy symmetry is still obeyed. This allows us to formulate the energy conservation law in terms of "potential energy" and keep the "total energy" intact.

The story of momentum is about the same. If you throw things, the acceleration changes their momentum. So no, space is not uniform, it is curved by gravity (which is equivalent to acceleration). However, this also is easily fixed by introducing the gravitational "force". Gravitation is not a force, but if you assume it is, then your momentum is conserved again.

The proper understanding of momentum conservation is not that momentum is always conserved or that it is only conserved in a uniform space. The proper understanding is that momentum is in a symmetry relationship with space. So if space is not uniform, then we are not all lost. We simply introduce a correction in a form of "gravitational force" and this component restores the momentum conservation.

So the answer to your question is that space is not uniform under acceleration, but the space/momentum symmetry is still obeyed. This allows us to add a correction of "gravitational force" that restores the momentum conservation.

I will let others correct me if I am wrong, but I do not see how acceleration could change the angular momentum of, say, a flywheel. So I'd venture to say that the space isotropiy is not changed by acceleration or at least locally by gravitation. I would welcome learning more, if I am missing anything here.

Comment: a very nice answer which has my one and only upvote

Comment: @veronika Thank you Veronika! (Is the stress on "i" in the third syllable?) Sadly this site is extremely close minded. Most answers are by the stagnated textbook and no original thought is appreciated.